# Java SocketException: Network is unreachable, but the URL works in the browser

Tags: java, sockets, http

I am trying to read some data via a GET request as

```
URL corpusDbUrl = null;
        try {
            corpusDbUrl = new URL("http://xxx.cc.ww.tt:1234/erwet/erherh/iouiiu");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        URLConnection corpusDbConn = null;
        try {
            corpusDbConn = corpusDbUrl.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(corpusDbConn.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        String inputLine="";

        try {
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
                   System.out.println(inputLine);
        } catch (Exception e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and i get

`java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable`

but when i try the URL in browser, it works just fine. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `http://xxx.cc.ww.tt:1234/erwet/erherh/iouiiu` seems not to be a working url

Comment: (a) Do you run the Java code on the same machine as the browser? (b) Does the browser have any proxy settings?

Comment: i have obfuscated the url for this post on SO

Comment: yes, the java code is no the same machine as the browser. there are no proxy settings

Comment: No virtual machines or dockers of any sort? Otherwise it may be a packet filtering issue. In any case, the problem doesn't seem to be in the code, so I don't think anybody here will be able to help you.

Comment: The browser is probably getting it from its cache.

Comment: try pinging the url from the command line

Comment: i dont think so. i made changes to the database which feeds the URL and the changes are reflected in the browser

Comment: pinging from command line works perfectly

Comment: i am trying to run this from a server in eclipse, could that be a problem?

Comment: use a network sniffer, place a break point before attempting the connection and see what happens

Comment: basically, i have a springboot app which communicates with a URL. the springboot app is running locally from via a server from eclipse

Comment: What do you mean by "A server from eclipse"?

Comment: tomcat server within eclipse